# Gallery unable to show image

Tags: android, file, storage, file-permissions, permission-denied

I am storing image file into application path i.e "/data/user/0/app_name". When I tried to open saved image into Gallery via Intent.ACTION_VIEW, its throwing exception like "java.io.FileNotFoundException" and "open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)".

Same thing was working fine when I was storing file on external storage. But due to privacy and security i need to save files into my app folder. For that I have used "getApplicationInfo().dataDir" to get path.

Please suggest what i need to do.

Note: App have below permissions
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`

This permission is granted.

Comment: You save in getFilesDir() because you want privacy. You clearly succeeded. The Gallery app has no access there. And your app does not need read or write permission for getFilesDir().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep the file in private internal memory then use a FileProvider to serve the file.

Store the file in getFilesDir().